# jQuery - Animate backgroundColor, depending on width percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm in the process of constructing rank/score bars for my device spec pages, and I have a basic animation using `transition` and `animation` together, but the end result isn't quite what I'm after. For your delectation, the CSS code is left in place (with the `animation` properties disabled), and [this is currently how it stands](http://v9.dylricho.com/temp/) - [JSFiddle of the same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/TfcRB/).

[A previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305710/change-div-background-color-depending-on-its-width) was to get the animation working, depending on the percentage of the bar, and the method I'm currently using is from the selected answer in that question. Unfortunately, the end result, while nice, doesn't provide the functionality I was originally after.

For example, as it currently is, the specific background color is provided when the page loads, and then the transition plays through.

What I was ideally after, is the result you get when the `animation` properties are enabled in my CSS, but again, that has problems of its own. It's closer to my target, but not the solution.

What I'm looking for is something like this (hopefully I have explained this well enough). All of these changes to the background color should happen while the transition (for the width) is happening.

- When `width` equals 0% to 24%, the background color should be red, and so the bars will start off as red - `#a41818`
- If `width` equals 25% to 49%, the background color should fade from red to orange - `#87581c`
- If `width` equals 50% to 74%, the background color should fade from orange to yellow - `#997815`
- If `width` equals 75% to 89%, the background color should fade from yellow to greenyellow - `#659a1f`
- If `width` equals 25% to 49%, the background color should fade from greenyellow to green - `#3a8d24`

And also, if the width happens to stay at a specific percentage, such as 56%, for example, then the bar background color should stay at the color respective to its percentage range. In this case, 56% would be yellow. If the bar width is 12%, the color should stay red, etc.

Please do let me know if you need more detail, or if you need further clarification with anything.

Thanks!

Comment: So the bar should cycle through each of the colours on its way to the final colour? Incidentally, as before, please post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or similar live demo) showing your code as it currently stands.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking for resp. what the problem is. Can’t you just define classes in your CSS for the desired start (and maybe end?) colors – and then assign those classes on load depending on the bar width …?

Comment: @DavidThomas Hi David, thank you responding, it's greatly appreciated. The colors should cycle through during the width transition, until the width stops at its specified value. And when the width stops, the color should also stop, with the end color being relative to the range of percentages I've given above. So if the bar was 95%, the colors would indeed cycle all the way through to green, but if the bar was only 30%, the color would stop at orange (but still fade from red to orange). [Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfcRB/). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to animate colors based on what percent you're at when animating. Is this correct?

If so, and based on what you've provided with your example, I'd recommend looking into jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function and using the `step` callback to check every step of the way in the animation.

Here is what I've experimented with so far with both css and jquery combined. I'd love to see a full css example!

The jQuery

```
// wrap this in an anonymous to help namespace collisions
// and to help with faster variable lookup.
;(function (document, $) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.rating-bar').each(function () {
            var _this = $(this),
                size = _this.data('size');

            _this.animate({
                width: size + '%'
            }, {
                duration: 2500,
                step: function (progress) {
                    _this.css({
                        backgroundColor: progressColor(progress)
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function progressColor(progress) {
        if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 24) return '#a41818';
        else if (progress >= 25 && progress <= 49) return '#87581c';
        else if (progress >= 50 && progress <= 74) return '#997815';
        else if (progress >= 75 && progress <= 89) return '#659a1f';
        else if (progress >= 90 && progress <= 100) return '#659a1f';
    }
})(document, jQuery);
```

The updated css

```
#rank-bar {
    margin: 1em 0 2em 0;
}
#rank-bar-score {
    display: inline-block;
}
#ranks-js {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.rating-bar {
    width: 0;
    line-height: 2;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    outline: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
}
.rating-bar-bg {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 1em;
    border: 1px solid #090909;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.rating-bar-bg-overall {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    border: 1px solid #090909;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.rb-label {
    width: 10em;
    max-width: 350px;
    display: block;
    color: #ebebeb;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 0 #222222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
#overall {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/TfcRB/7/)

**EDIT**: I've added the updated css from the fiddle.

**EDIT 2**: For a simple example, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/8aAGb/).

Comment: Hi Dennis, that is exactly what I'm after. Thank you so much, greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but for unknown reasons, it doesn't seem to want to work over on my website. [Here is the webpage in question](http://v9.dylricho.com/temp/). Aside from the last color for 90-100%, the code is directly copied over from your JSFiddle.

Comment: @DylRicho Did you copy the css also? EDIT: I've added the edited css from the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: I didn't realize the CSS was modified originally, but I now have the updated CSS as well, and still nothing.

Comment: @DylRicho Oh! I think I can see your problem. You didn't stick the code provided inside of a `$(document).ready();`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it.

The animation done with CSS, and scripting just to handle when to stop.

script

```
var intervalFunc;
var containerWidth;
var stopAt;

$(document).ready(function() {


$("#run").click(function() {
    containerWidth = $("#container").width();
    entered = $("#value").val();
    stopAt = containerWidth * entered / 100; 
    $("#test").removeClass ("animated");
    intervalFunc = setInterval (Stop, 10);
    setTimeout (Start, 10);
});

})

function Start () {
    $("#test").addClass ("animated");
    $("#test").removeAttr("style");

}

function Stop () {
    var elem = document.getElementById('test');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle (elem, null);
    var frame = style.getPropertyValue("width");
    var width = parseInt(frame,10);
    if (width > stopAt) {
        elem.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
        clearInterval (intervalFunc);
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: block;
    top: 40px;
}

#test {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: colors;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#run {
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colors
{
    0% {width: 0%; background-color: red;}
   30% {           background-color: red;}
   50% {           background-color: yellow;}
  100% {width: 100%; background-color: green;}
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KJPEY/)

In the demo, enter the percentage of the bar, and press run.

Only webkit animations, but should be easily extended to other browsers.

The color stops are only aproximate, but again can be easily modified.